# text assigned to String attribute does not store properly

Tags: text, attributes, assign

I have assigned a text from a txt file to three attributes, but whenever I call any of those attributes with a Get Method to another class, the value displayed is "null".

Furthermore, I have confirmed that these values are displayed in the method leerArchivo (whenever I use a println for m_linea1-2-3).

Please Help.

```
public class ArchivoCasillas 
{
    String m_linea1;
    String m_linea2;
    String m_linea3;

public void crearArchivo()
{
    try
    {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("ReglasDelTablero.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);

        bw.write("<7,0> , <0,0>");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("<4,1> , <7,2> | <2,7> , <5,5> | <1,2> , <7,4> | <0,4> , <2,5>");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("<7,7> , <3,6> | <6,4> , <3,5> | <4,0> , <2,1> | <2,4> , <0,3>");

        bw.close();
    } 
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("error");
    }
}

public void leerArchivo()
{
    String linea;
    int i = 1;
    try
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("ReglasDelTablero.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        Tablero serpientesEscaleras = new Tablero();

        while( (linea = br.readLine() ) != null)
        {    
            switch(i)
            {
                case 1: m_linea1 = linea;
                break;
                case 2: m_linea2 = linea;
                break;
                case 3: m_linea3 = linea;
                break;
            }

            i++;
        }

        br.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
}

public String getM_linea1()
{
    return m_linea1;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was a conceptual problem on my part. I created an Object in another class, but I never called the leerArchivo method with that object, therefore, the value of the attributes was null. Leaving an answer in case it's useful for someone in the future, as I didn't get a reply.